# How can I reduce my network speed of Windows 7 64b OS?

Tags: windows-7, local-area-network, network-monitoring

I want to reduce network speed of my OS for testing my application. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a number of software to do this.

Google up for the 'network shaping software` keywords.

[here](http://www.softperfect.com/products/bandwidth/) is one, random pick (Might not be for 64bits though).

This is useful when on a domestic LAN, you want to make sure some long running traffic (P2P, streaming...) do not interfere with response time of other interactive activities (surfing...).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about physical network, take a look at the network drivers - there's usually an option there for connecting at a certain speed, which by default will probably be set to 'auto negotiate' - you can set this to connect at a lower speed, and hopefully all should work.

Virtual is a problem - regardless of what speed you tell the network to work at, for all 'internal' communication between VMs on the same host it will work at computer bus speed.

Answer (score 0):

You basically do not. Not found any sensible functionality for that within Windows, nor did I mange to find proper tools for that oudside windows.

Network driver wont help you unless you want to work in a 10000/100/10mbit granularity. I assume you talk about simulating internet speeds (some mbit, possibly some hundred kbit), not just going dow nto 100mbit from 1000 ;)

Your best bet would be to get a small capable router (Mikrotik 750, 40 USD or so) that has QOS queue control then put that in within the LAN. THIs allows you control over the speed quite extensible. They normally are used on internet side of WISPs (Wireless internet providers) which need a lot of QOS (Quality of Service)., but the low price of the 750G (or the 450G for all what matters) makes it feasible to just get one for controlling network bandwidths in a lab.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is web-based you can get Throttling plugins for certain browsers e.g. http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/FirefoxThrottle.aspx

Otherwise your network card can be switched from Auto to 100Mbit / 10Mbit etc by going to 'Network and Sharing Centre', then clicking on your Local Area Connection, clicking the Configure button and then going to the 'Advanced' tab. Once there click the 'Speed and Duplex' property and change the 'Value' drop-down box from 'Auto' to what ever speed you desire.